# How install latest version of baloo on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu, repository, baloo

I installed Baloo search on Ubuntu 18.04. It gave me version `4:5.44.0-0ubuntu1`.

Looking for a more recent version I found the [kubuntu ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports). That says it has Bakoo version `5.47.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04~ppa2`.

I added the ppa and installed Baloo again:

$ sudo apt install baloo

```
add kubuntu repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

But apt said I already have the 'newest version': `4:5.44.0-0ubuntu1` .

I am assuming it is simply okay to install Kubuntu packages on Ubuntu, and that the ppa to use to install kde or kubuntu packages on Ubuntu is kubuntu-ppa/backports.

What do I do to get the latest version. Are there any good reasons why I should not? And is there a better place to get it. (I notice Baloo seems not to be available as a Flatpak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, [don't](https://askubuntu.com/a/1225827/297529). But you cannot post an answer to StackExchange that is less than 30 characters, so I'll say it again: just don't.